# Highlight columns in word file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm hoping someone may be able to help me with word macro. Some times receive i receive word files which have tables in them. and i have to highlight text in last column. but if there are brakes in table or new table i cannot select entire column.
ex

| source | target |
| --- | --- |
| text | text to highlight |
| Cell 3 | text to highlight |

i tried recording macro but not working.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdColumn, Extend:=True
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdColumn, Extend:=True
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    ActiveDocument.Save`

End Sub
```

Comment: Are there merged cells within the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```vb
Public Sub highlightColumns()
Dim tbl As Table
For Each tbl In ThisDocument.Tables
    With tbl
        highlightColumn tbl, .Columns.Count
    End With
Next
End Sub

Private Sub highlightColumn(tbl As Table, colIndex As Long)

Dim col As Column, c As Cell

With tbl
    On Error Resume Next    ' in case there are merged cells
    Set col = .Columns(colIndex)
    Select Case Err
        Case 0  'no error
            'true shading - better performance as it is not necessary to iterate through cells
            'col.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdYellow
            
            For Each c In col.Cells
                c.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
            Next
            
        Case 5992   'merged cells - then we can't use column
            Err.Clear
            
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set c = .Cell(1, colIndex)
            Do
                If c.ColumnIndex = colIndex Then
                    c.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                End If
                Set c = c.Next
            Loop Until c Is Nothing
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Description
    End Select
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
End Sub
```

It loops through all tables of the document (`Sub hightlightColumns`)

Per table last column is highlighted. (`Sub highlightColumn`)

In case there are merged cells an error is thrown (5992). In this case the code iterates over all cells of the table.

Comment: Thank you for your help this worked. But it had to make one change in code

"For Each tbl In ThisDocument.Tables" to "For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables"